# Call method till it returns value

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I want to call a method till it returns a value in my `WPF` app.

```
void btnDecode_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var task = new Task(task);
    task.Start();
    task.Wait();
}

async void task()
{
    Task<object> result= DecodedResult((BitmapSource)imageBarcode.Source);
    object i = await result;
    txtBarcodeContent.Text = i.ToString();
}

async Task<object> DecodedResult(BitmapSource renderTargetBitmap)
{
    var reader = new BarcodeReader();
    txtBarcodeContent.Text = "reading";

    return reader.Decode(renderTargetBitmap);
}
```

But it throws me an error on `task.Start();`

> "Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object
>   because a different thread owns it."

Why can't I access it and why does another thread own it?

Comment: "it throws me error" doesn't say where it's failing - what is "it" here? Please be clearer. (It's also odd to have an `async` method and then start it as a new task explicitly. Why not just make it `async Task mjau` - or ideally with a better name...)

Comment: Also, please specify more context - is this a web-app? WinForm?

Comment: possible duplicate of [The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10795948/the-calling-thread-cannot-access-this-object-because-a-different-thread-owns-it)

Comment: Just google with the exception message first.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer if it asked thousand times... then show me clear answer and solution for this problem... I searched but didn't find any working solution for me.

Comment: @John Oh yeah, use the search function both in SO or Google. Look for *how to modify a control property from other thread than UI*...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you update your UI elements from a thread other than the main thread, you need to use:

```
this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
{
       ...// your code here.
}));
```

You can also use control.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() to check whether the current thread owns the control. If it does own it, your code looks as normal. Otherwise, use above pattern.

Comment: This is the common solution, but is unnecessary with async.

Answer (score 1):

This is illegal from anywhere but the UI thread.

```
txtBarcodeContent.Text = i.ToString();
```

And `task.Wait();` ruins the async effect.

## Solution

You can have `async` on the click method.

This works: Note I only `async` when I `await` and I avoid `async void` ([Using async without await](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12016567/using-async-without-await)).

```
private async void btnDecode_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string result = await DecodedResult((BitmapSource)imageBarcode.Source);
    txtBarcodeContent.Text = result;
}

private async Task<string> DecodedResult(BitmapSource renderTargetBitmap)
{
    object decoded = await reader.Decode(renderTargetBitmap);
    return decoded.ToString();
}
```

Comment: Apologies should have been `private async void btnDecode_Click`